# Can't add any roles to Facebook app

Tags: facebook, roles

I need to add another admin to my FB app (however, I also tried this with developer and test roles).

I paste their name, and press Send. Facebook closes window and proceeds to quickly "flash" a colored box that pushes my own admin box down (as if a box for another role was created), but it's immediately removed (hence the flash). No error message is displayed, but the role wasn't added either.

Coincidentally: Not the first weird problem I had with FB, FB refused to allow me to display app lists/add app with my company's account, and only allowed it on my personal account. They don't answer support requests either. Bleh.

Answer (score 8):

First make sure the other person has [verified their account](https://www.facebook.com/help/?faq=167551763306531).

I worked around this by entering their numeric facebook ID into the developer app. Apparently it's unable to work with email or custom name.

Go to http://graph.facebook.com/their_facebook_name and copy the number after `"id":`. Put that in the box. Presto.

I don't think this is a chance occurrence because the problem also appeared when I created a new app using the coworker's account and tried to add myself as the second admin.

Shame on you, Facebook.

Comment: Nice work! Yep the ID did the trick - custom name was causing the issue. Another little 'gotcha' for the FB developers labyrinth!

Comment: Thanks! I was running into a similar issue. Entering email addresses just gets a non-response. But entering the ID worked perfectly. Not exactly a documented feature. :/

Comment: You need to register yourself as a developer on developers.facebook.com